# Porque no puedo entrar a Mysql desde Cmd pero si en el Command Line Client

Tags: mysql, cmd

Estoy en `Windows 10` y estoy intentando entrar a `Mysql` en mi *localhost* desde `cmd` pero me sale este error, con el usuario `root`

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql -u root -p Enter
> password: **** ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
> 'localhost' (10061)

Pero si entro en desde el `Command Line Client` si me deja entrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente reiniciando el servicio.

Alguien sabe el porqué y la solución?

Comment: Verifica que el usuario tenga permisos para acceder desde localhost.

Comment: estoy usando el usuario root

Comment: No importa si eres root o cualquier otro usuario, puede ser cuestión de permisos. Aunque probablemente se deba al plugin de autenticación que se está utilizando, en las versiones 5.7+ se usa `auth_socket` en lugar de `mysql_native_password`. Solo basta con realizar ese cambio para que puedas acceder. Te recomiendo la [siguiente lectura](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-mysql-en-ubuntu-18-04-es), un artículo de DIgitalOcean en el que explican el proceso, revisa en especial el paso 3, creo que es el que puede ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por tu ayuda ricardo-dlc si era eso aunque me salia un error de socket y lo solucione con update user set plugin="auth_socket" where User='root
Muchas gracias